# Create only one instance of Media Player

Tags: android, audio, media-player, instance, android-mediaplayer

I play sound files in a web view calling them with Javascript.

This is the code I use, but it creates each time I call a new sound an instance of `mediaplayer` so I cant't stop already playing sounds and there are too many media players running.

```
public class AudioInterface {
    Context mContext;

    AudioInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    //Play an audio file from the webpage
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playAudio(String aud) {
        final MediaPlayer mp;
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor =
                    mContext.getAssets().openFd(aud);

            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(),
                fileDescriptor.getLength());
            fileDescriptor.close();
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

How to create only one instance of `mediaplayer` so it will stop the current sound before playing the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this. Notice how I initialized MediaPlayer outside of `playAudio(...)`:

```
public class AudioInterface {

    Context mContext;
    final MediaPlayer mp;

    AudioInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    // Play an audio file from the webpage
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playAudio(String aud) {

        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = mContext.getAssets().openFd(aud);

            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), fileDescriptor.getLength());
            fileDescriptor.close();
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```